# Issues with this.setState and this.state while updating an array in React JS

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to display list of tables in the database if user presses '+'button and remove the list of tables when '-' button is pressed. My code is:

```js
class DatabaseItem extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      tabList : [],
      plusIsNext : true
    };
  }

  flagOn(){
    this.setState({
      plusIsNext:!this.state.plusIsNext
    });
  }
  showTables(){
    if(this.state.plusIsNext){
      httpUtil.get(`http://localhost:4553/api?query=
      SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'`,this.props.dbname).then(response => {
        this.setState({
          tabList:response.data
        })
      });
    }
    else{
      let arr = [];
      this.state.tabList = [];
      console.log(this.state.tabList);
    }
    this.flagOn();
  }
  render(){
    let sign = this.state.plusIsNext ? '+':'-';
    return(
      <div key ={this.props.dbname} >
        <button onClick ={() => {this.showTables()}}>{sign}</button><a>{this.props.dbname}</a>
        {this.state.tabList.map(table => {
          return(
            <div key = {table.table_name}>{table.table_name}</div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For now I have updated the value of tabList directly by reassigning empty array [] to this.state.tabList and it works. If I press the + button tables of the particular database is shown and if I press the - button the  list disappears. But if I use the setState to reassign empty array to tabList, the tabList doesn't get empty.

```
this.setState({
      tabList:[]
    })
```

### or

```js
let arr = [];
this.setState({
  tabList:arr
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue was the flagOn call. Because JS is asynchronous, it is best not to call setState more than once at a time. What happens is it calls the http request, jumps to the flagOn and calls setState, then comes back to request once its complete and setState once again.

I refactored your code by consolidating these calls into your conditional. If I understood your code flow properly, this should work!

```
class DatabaseItem extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      tabList : [],
      plusIsNext : true
    };

    this.showTables = this.showTables.bind(this)
  }

  showTables(){
    if (this.state.plusIsNext) {
      httpUtil.get(`http://localhost:4553/api?query=
      SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'`,this.props.dbname).then(response => {
        this.setState({ 
          tabList: response.data,
          plusIsNext: false
        })
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ 
        tabList: [],
        plusIsNext: true
      })
    }
  }

  render(){
    let sign = this.state.plusIsNext ? '+':'-';
    return(
      <div key ={this.props.dbname} >
        <button onClick={this.showTables}>{sign}</button><a>{this.props.dbname}</a>
        {this.state.tabList.map(table => {
          return(
            <div key = {table.table_name}>{table.table_name}</div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. This fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should call setState once only, after you have fetched the data or empty list:

```
*showTables(){
  let _tabList = []
  let _plusNext = true

    if (this.state.plusIsNext) {
      yield httpUtil.get(`http://localhost:4553/api?query=
      SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'`,this.props.dbname).then(response => {

          _tabList = response.data
          _plusNext = false
      });
    } 

    yield this.setState({ tabList: _tabList, plusIsNext: _plusNext})
  }
```

Edit:
Converted the function to generator function.

Comment: I saw what was wrong with my code. corrected it. ( : instead of = )

Comment: There is a problem with your code. The `httpUtil.get` is asynchronous. That means when `this.setState` is called, `httpUtil.get` might have not returned (or even have not been executed).

Comment: Thanks @WinChiu. I have edited my code. Hopefully it should work now

Comment: what does yield do? and wont removing the else condition cause the setState below to get executed regardless of the valuse of plusIsNext?

Comment: I wrote a generator function. `yield` make sure to complete the execution before next `yield`, thus works as synchronous execution. If I look at your code, you are calling `setState` at both place - `if` and `else`. What I did it is, defined the variables and values which you are doing in `else` condition. If, `if` condition is true, your tabList and plusIsNext will be having values, otherwise the state will have empty tab list and false (as same as else condition)